# How to match complex strings with regular expressions

Tags: c++, regex

I am a newbie in C++, I am using the regular expression function, but I have not been able to get the results I want

c++ code:

```
#include <regex>

std::string str = "[game.exe+009E820C]+338";
std::smatch result;
std::regex pattern("\\[([^\\[\\]]+)\\]");

std::regex_match(str, result, pattern);

// no result
std::cout << result[1] << std::endl;
```

I am familiar with javascript regular expressions, so I can get the value I want:

```
'[game.exe+009E820C]+338'.match(/\[([^\[\]]+)\]/)[1]   =>   game.exe+009E820C
```

Is my c++ code doing something wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to access the capture groups, it appears that the `regex_match` API requires a pattern which matches the entire input.  Also, to avoid getting bogged down by a negative character class which includes a closing square bracket, I recommend using the Perl lazy dot instead.  Putting all this together:

```
std::string str = "[game.exe+009E820C]+338";
std::smatch result;
std::regex pattern(".*\\[(.*?)\\].*");
std::regex_match(str, result, pattern);
std::cout << result[1] << std::endl;
```

This prints:

```
game.exe+009E820C
```